# remove sibling of rating star function JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, rating

I have a JS  function rating , it's work, but this one rate all stars of my list.
 I would like to remove the siblings attribut to rate just one ligne

```js
function rating () {
    let $star_rating = $('li #starRating');
    let SetRatingStar = function () {
        return $star_rating.each(function () {
            if (parseInt($star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
                return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
            } else {
                return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
            }
        });
    };

    $star_rating.on('click', function () {
        $star_rating.siblings('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
        return SetRatingStar();
    });

}
```

I try this but my code don t work, i can t change the class of stars ( i have remove 'siblings').

```js
function rating () {
    let $star_rating = $('li #starRating');
    let SetRatingStar =function () {
        return $star_rating.each(function () {
            if (parseInt($star_rating('input.rating-value').val()) >= parseInt($(this).data('rating'))) {
                return $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
            } else {
                return $(this).removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
            }
        });
    };

    $star_rating.on('click', function () {
        $star_rating('input.rating-value').val($(this).data('rating'));
        return SetRatingStar();
    });

}
```

This is the code of my view

```html
<div class="d-inline-flex">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" onclick="toggle(this);">
    <p class="mt-3 mb-0 ml-1">Tous vus</p>
</div>
{% for episode in episodes %}
    <li class="list-group-item bgt">
        {% if episode.hasSeen == 0 %}
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ episode.id }}" name="hasSeen" onclick="processForm(this)">
        {% else %}
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{ episode.id }}" name="hasSeen" checked="checked" onclick="processForm(this)">
        {% endif %}
        {{ "E%02d" | format (episode.number) }} - {{ episode.title }}
        {% for i in  1..5 %}
            {% set classNote = (i<= episode.note ? "" : i - episode.note < 0.5 ? "-half-full" : "-o" ) %}
            <span class="fa fa-lg fa-star{{ classNote }}" id="starRating" data-rating="{{ i }}" onclick="rating(this)"></span>
            <input type="hidden" name="whatever1" class="rating-value" value="{{ episode.note }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Should I point out that you can only have one element with an `id`?

Comment: You'd probably want to use `class="starRating"` and `.starRating` instead.